# Share background between absolute svg element and relative element

Tags: html, css, svg

This might be an XY problem, as I am not too familiar with CSS, I have been able to google about the involved parts individually, but I haven't seen anything that combines them.

I need to add a background in a `navbar`, but I also want an after `svg` element that goes over the image under it to have that image as a fill in, so I need both the `navbar` *and* the `svg` to use the same background.

[This](https://pqina.nl/blog/set-svg-background-image-fill-color/) blog post seems to cover the "using an image as a fill of an SVG", but I as I mentioned, haven't been able to combine that with also using it as a background of another element

This is the code I've got so far:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        body, p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 10 10 5 15;
        }

        .navbar a {
            margin-right: 10;
        }

        nav::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            height: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/23618/rip.svg) bottom;
            background-size: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<nav>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<body>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/13/36/triangle-161210_1280.png">
</body>
```

It produces this (notice the rip effect *over* the ruler):

[image]

Say I wanted to add [this](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/21/05/24/vintage-4420182_1280.jpg) image (another royalty-free image) as the background image of the `navbar`, it should end up looking like this (crude GIMP editing):

[image]

Comment: First of all, you got some major errors to fix here. `nav` does not go between `head` and `body`, it belongs _into_ `body`. And you got several lengths values in your CSS, that miss a unit.

Comment: Second, your SVG has a white part on top, and then towards the bottom, there are transparent parts that create this "ripple" effect. You won't be able to just "replace" those white parts with an image, without modifying the SVG itself. Might make sense to chose a different approach here to begin with, such as a clip-path or a mask image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach: Instead of trying to mask the triangle with a separate svg, make the triangle rippled inside a png, and then position it accordingly, like so:

```css
/*new CSS code from here*/

nav{
height: 40px;
background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/21/05/24/vintage-4420182_1280.jpg') repeat-x 6px;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
width: 1280px;
}
.triangle{
top:63px;
position: absolute;
left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        body, p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 10 10 5 15;
        }

        .navbar a {
            margin-right: 10;
        }

        nav::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            height: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background-size: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<nav>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<body>
    <img class="triangle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGW2R.png">
</body>
```

The image: [image]